# Magento 2 unable to download Braintree Payments using composer

Tags: magento2.3, checkout, payment-methods, paypal, braintree

Using Magento 2.3.5-p1
We are trying to download Braintree Payments - https://marketplace.magento.com/paypal-module-braintree.html

Using these commands - composer require paypal/module-braintree

Getting this error -

```
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove magento/project-community-edition 2.3.5-p1
    - Conclusion: remove magento/product-community-edition 2.3.5-p1
    - magento/project-community-edition 2.3.5-p1 requires magento/product-community-edition 2.3.5-p1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.5-p1].
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/product-community-edition 2.3.5-p1
    - paypal/module-braintree 4.2.5 requires paypal/module-braintree-core 4.2.5 -> satisfiable by paypal/module-braintree-core[4.2.5].
    - Conclusion: don't install paypal/module-braintree-core 4.2.5
    - paypal/module-braintree 4.2.4 requires paypal/module-braintree-core 4.2.4 -> satisfiable by paypal/module-braintree-core[4.2.4].
    - Conclusion: don't install paypal/module-braintree-core 4.2.4
    - paypal/module-braintree 4.2.2-p1 requires paypal/module-braintree-core 4.2.3-p1 -> satisfiable by paypal/module-braintree-core[4.2.3-p1].
    - Conclusion: don't install paypal/module-braintree-core 4.2.3-p1
    - paypal/module-braintree 4.2.2 requires paypal/module-braintree-core 4.2.2 -> satisfiable by paypal/module-braintree-core[4.2.2].
    - Conclusion: don't install paypal/module-braintree-core 4.2.2
    - Installation request for magento/project-community-edition 2.3.5-p1 -> satisfiable by magento/project-community-edition[2.3.5-p1].
    - paypal/module-braintree 4.2.1 requires paypal/module-braintree-core 4.2.1 -> satisfiable by paypal/module-braintree-core[4.2.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install paypal/module-braintree-core 4.2.1
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.5-p1 requires magento/module-braintree 100.3.5 -> satisfiable by magento/module-braintree[100.3.5].
    - paypal/module-braintree-core 4.2.0 conflicts with magento/module-braintree[100.3.5].
    - paypal/module-braintree-core 4.2.0 conflicts with magento/module-braintree[100.3.5].
    - paypal/module-braintree-core 4.2.0 conflicts with magento/module-braintree[100.3.5].
    - paypal/module-braintree 4.2.0 requires paypal/module-braintree-core 4.2.0 -> satisfiable by paypal/module-braintree-core[4.2.0].
    - Installation request for paypal/module-braintree ^4.2 -> satisfiable by paypal/module-braintree[4.2.5, 4.2.2-p1, 4.2.4, 4.2.2, 4.2.1, 4.2.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

How to solve this?

Comment: It is conflicting with the already installed Braintree module at `vendor/magento/module-braintree`

Comment: yes,then how to resolve this ?